# On integrating decay time of binary star's orbital evaporation.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I am currently researching on binary systems and their orbital evaporation due to gravitational radiation. The binary stars have a highly elliptic orbit($\epsilon\approx1$). I have obtained the following integral for finding the decay time of the orbits( the orbits would eventually decay into a circular one):
$$T(a_{0},e_{0})=\frac{12(c_{0}^4)}{19\gamma}\int_{0}^{e_0}{\frac{e^{29/19}[1+(121/304)e^2]^{1181/2299}}{(1-e^2)^{3/2}}}de\tag1$$
Where $$\gamma=\frac{64G^3}{5c^5}m_{1}m_{2}(m_{1}+m_{2})$$
For $e_{0}$ close to $1$ the equation becomes:
$$T(a_{0},e_{0})\approx\frac{768}{425}T_{f}a_{0}(1-e_{0}^2)^{7/2}\tag2$$
Where $$T_{f}=\frac{a_{0}^4}{4\gamma}$$
And $\gamma$ has the same value as define do above.
I am stuck with $(1)$ and $(2)$; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More a comment, but I lack the reputation to add comments:

- The lhs of $(1)$ says that $T$ depends on $a_0$, but the rhs doesn't contain it.
- According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E(3%2F2%2By)*(1%2BA*x%5E2)%5E(1%2F2%2Bz)%2F(1-x%5E2)%5E(3%2F2)), the integral in $(1)$ can be solved using the Appell hypergeometric function $F_1$.

Comment: yes thanks for reminding me, that's because the approximated answer to T: $T(a_{0},e_{0})\approx\frac{a_{0}^4}{4\gamma}$ hence the dependence on $a_{0}$ and also due to the fact that $a_{0}$ determines $e_{0}$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: And also $T$ would depend on $a_{0}$ for small $e_{0}$ in accordance to what is mentioned above. Any idea on the second one? I'm thinking we ought to use numerical methods to find the answer for $e_{0}$...